# How to sort and filter searches on multiple fields in SQL

Tags: php, sql, database, search, search-engine

I have a SQL database with music songs. Each song of course has an artist, an album and a genre. They also have a general 'popularity' counter, which was obtained from an external source. However, I want to give users the opportunity to vote on the songs as well. In the end, the search results should be ordered on this popularity, as well as the accuracy of the results with the original query.

The current query I use is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM p2pm_tracks
WHERE
 `artist` LIKE '%$searchquestion%' OR
 `genres` LIKE '%$searchquestion%' OR
 `trackname` LIKE '%$searchquestion%' OR
 `album_name` LIKE '%$searchquestion%'
ORDER BY `popularity` DESC
LIMIT $startingpoint, $resultsperpage
```

I struggle with the following:

1. Users search for something. I look in all fields: song *title*, *artist*, *album* and *genre*. However, usually a certain search query contains (parts of) multiple of these tracks.

For instance, a user might search for `Opening Philip Glass`.

In this case, the first word is the *name of the song*, and the second and third words are the *artist name*.

Another example:

If I split the query on spaces, the correct tracks are found. However, if another track that matches only one of these words has a higher popularity, it will be returned before the one that actually accurately matches the search query.

I still want to sort the results in a way that things that match bigger parts of the query at once are at the top. How can I do that using SQL?

2. I have the static popularity and want to create a new one. Therefore, I want to use the average of all votes on a certain track (these votes are stored in another table), except in the cases where there are no votes yet. **How can I construct a SQL query that does this?**

My application is built in PHP, but I would like to do as much as possible of this in SQL, preferably in as few queries as possible to reduce latency.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SQL isn't the best way to accomplish this. A text search engine (e.g., Solr Lucene) is a much better way, especially if you're allowing searches like `opening philip glass`. Some RDBMSs (e.g., SQL Server) do have full-text engines built in, and might be suitable.

Comment: Also note that your MySQL query right now is vulnerable to SQL injection this way. Always escape your queries.

Comment: You can sort it on server side using levenstein http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: I would love to give you an answer but I need some sql dump to work on first, if you can send me that, I think I can help you.

Comment: @Ruben: Do not worry, I sanitize my statements before inserting them into the query. I did learn from this: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a weight for every column in your search results.

Here's the code:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN `artist` LIKE '%$searchquestion%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS artist_match,
    CASE WHEN `genres` LIKE '%$searchquestion%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS genres_match,
    CASE WHEN `trackname` LIKE '%$searchquestion%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS trackname_match,
    CASE WHEN `album_name` LIKE '%$searchquestion%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS album_name_match,
FROM p2pm_tracks
WHERE
 `artist` LIKE '%$searchquestion%' OR
 `genres` LIKE '%$searchquestion%' OR
 `trackname` LIKE '%$searchquestion%' OR
 `album_name` LIKE '%$searchquestion%'
ORDER BY 
 `artist_match` DESC,
 `genres_match` DESC,
 `trackname_match` DESC,
 `album_name_match` DESC,
 `popularity` DESC,
LIMIT $startingpoint, $resultsperpage
```

This query will gather the results related to:

- the artist FIRST,
- THEN the genre,
- THEN the track's title,
- THEN the album's name,
- THEN the popularity of the song

To optimize this query, you should **avoid** using "LIKE" and use "FULLTEXT SEARCH" instead.

The optimized code will be:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('$searchquestion') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS artist_match,
    CASE WHEN MATCH (genres) AGAINST ('$searchquestion') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS genres_match,
    CASE WHEN MATCH (trackname) AGAINST ('$searchquestion') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS trackname_match,
    CASE WHEN MATCH (album_name) AGAINST ('$searchquestion') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS album_name_match,
FROM p2pm_tracks
WHERE
 MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('$searchquestion') OR
 MATCH (genres) AGAINST ('$searchquestion') OR
 MATCH (trackname) AGAINST ('$searchquestion') OR
 MATCH (album_name) AGAINST ('$searchquestion')
ORDER BY 
 `artist_match` DESC,
 `genres_match` DESC,
 `trackname_match` DESC,
 `album_name_match` DESC,
 `popularity` DESC,
LIMIT $startingpoint, $resultsperpage
```

And make sure that you're using the MyISAM engine for the MySQL table and that you created indexes for the columns you want to search.
The code for your MySQL table should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE p2pm_tracks (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    artist VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    trackname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ...
    ...
    FULLTEXT (artist,trackname)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

For more info, check the following:
 - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html
 - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

If you're looking for something more advanced, then look into Solr (based on Lucene), Sphinx, ElasticSearch (based on Lucene) etc.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a whole lot. It is very good to know that it is possible to sort the results in such a way :-)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is not that good in searching for text :(

1. What you could try to do is take a look at full text search functionality (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)
2. With the match against function you can get a relevance where you can order on.

   SELECT p2pm_tracks.*,
      MATCH (artist, genres) AGAINST ('some words') AS relevance,
      MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('some words') AS artist_relevance

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use LIKE. It's very slow. You can use full text search in mysql but you can not determinate which column is more important.

Better solution is mysql with sphinx.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, to match your 1. example is difficult in SQL, I´m not sure if there is a function.
what you need is something like this funktion in php

http://php.net/manual/function.similar-text.php

Or you select in your sql query only per average vote and calculate how "good" the results match via php and the similar-text function.